# In CSS, how may I select elements which are *not* the descendants of a container element with a class conforming to a recognisable pattern?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Imagine that the HTML and CSS below is already set.

**What CSS rules can I add beneath the already-written CSS to make the red paragraphs display as red?**

```css
body,
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  margin: 6px;
}

.one-filter-one p,
p[class^="one-filter-one"] {
  color: blue;
}

.two-filter-two p,
p[class^="two-filter-two"] {
  color: green;
}

.four-filter-four p,
p[class^="four-filter-four"] {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="another-class">This is red.</p>
<p>This is red.</p>

<div class="one-filter-one">
  <p>This is blue.</p>
  <p class="one-filter-one--paragraph">This is blue.</p>
</div>

<p class="two-filter-two">This is green.</p> 

<p>This is red.</p> 
<p class="another-class-two">This is red.</p>

<div class="three-filter-three">
  <p>This is unstyled (black).</p>
  <div><p>This is unstyled (black) too.</p></div> 
</div>

<div class="four-filter-four">
  <p class="four-filter-four--sentence">This is orange.</p>
</div>
  
<p class="five-filter-five">This is also unstyled (black).</p>

<div class="another-class-three">
  <p>This is red.</p>
  <p class="another-class-four">This is red.</p>
</div>
```

---

My best guess is to use the `:not()` pseudo-class.

But I'm not entirely convinced this is the right approach, principally because I'm not sure that `:not()` can handle this case.

**My attempt at a solution, using `:not()`:**

```css
body,
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  margin: 6px;
}

.one-filter-one p,
p[class^="one-filter-one"] {
  color: blue;
}

.two-filter-two p,
p[class^="two-filter-two"] {
  color: green;
}

.four-filter-four p,
p[class^="four-filter-four"] {
  color: orange;
}

p:not([class*="-filter-"]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="another-class">This is red.</p>
<p>This is red.</p>

<div class="one-filter-one">
  <p>This is blue.</p>
  <p class="one-filter-one--paragraph">This is blue.</p>
</div>

<p class="two-filter-two">This is green.</p> 

<p>This is red.</p> 
<p class="another-class-two">This is red.</p>

<div class="three-filter-three">
  <p>This is unstyled (black).</p>
  <div><p>This is unstyled (black) too.</p></div> 
</div>

<div class="four-filter-four">
  <p class="four-filter-four--sentence">This is orange.</p> </div>
  
<p class="five-filter-five">This is also unstyled (black).</p>

<div class="another-class-three">
  <p>This is red.</p>
  <p class="another-class-four">This is red.</p>
</div>
```

Clearly this is not it, because I am not correctly selecting:

**NOT *descendant* elements of `[class*="-filter-"]`.**

But I'm not clear how to do this at all.

Is there any way to do this, or am I looking to achieve the impossible in 2020, given CSS's contemporary capabilities?

---

**Notes:**

Although, in 2020, the pseudo-class `:not()` has been around for the best part of a decade I've always tended to avoid using it. The only thing I do know is that the `:not()` pseudo-class function can only take simple (ie. not compound) selectors.

---

### Added:

Based on `@G-Cyrillus`' brilliant suggestion (in the comments, immediately below), I have come up with the following:

```
body > p:not([id*="-filter-"]):not([class*="-filter-"]),
body > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > p:not([id*="-filter-"]):not([class*="-filter-"]),
body > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > p:not([id*="-filter-"]):not([class*="-filter-"]),
body > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > p:not([id*="-filter-"]):not([class*="-filter-"]),
body > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > p:not([id*="-filter-"]):not([class*="-filter-"]) {
  color: red;
}
```

On the plus side this *does* work. (So, infinitely better than anything I had before).

On the minus side:

- it's verbose
- it's inelegant
- it only works to the fourth level of element-nesting
- I can of course carry on adding levels, but that only makes it verboser and ineleganter

Comment: You need to mind the structure too : `body>p:not([class]),
p[class]:not([class*="-filter-"]) {
  color: red;
}` would work here.if p without a class or with are also filtered.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - Thank you. I **_really_** like where you're heading with this. I adapted your suggestion above and came up with: `body > p:not([class]), body > :not([class*="-filter-"]) > p:not([class]), p[class]:not([class*="-filter-"]) { color: red; }` which is *definitely* on the right track... only I'm concerned about the _direct child selector_ (`>`) since when we've used it once, we need to repeatedly add more `>...>...>` rules below it (and such a list of rules could never be exhaustive).

Comment: maybe, the idea would be to give a red color by default to all ps, and reset to black or initial the left over ,  alike `p {color:red;} /* ... your selectors and finaly */ [class*="-filter-"]:not([class*="-filter-one"]) p:not([class]) , p[class="five-filter-five"]  {color:initial}` ? (based on snippet 2)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus _"red color by default"_ - Sure. This is what I would normally do: declare a baseline style and overwrite it when I need to in incrementally more complex contexts. That's how I've managed to avoid using `:not()` for the last decade. _**But**_ in this case, the _rewritten baseline styles_ are user-generated content (UGC) and, being added at the end, they cannot precede the original baseline styles... instead, they need to be able to _rewrite_ what has already been styled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a educational exercise.

The most significant thing it's taught me is that, given that `:not()` cannot accept *compound selectors*, it's very far from straightforward to handle subsequent *nested levels of markup* after applying `:not()`.

Given the following:

```css
.filter-1 {
  color: red;
}

:not([class^="filter-"]) p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filter-1">
  <div>
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

the second `<p>` *still* shows up `blue`.

Why? Because even though its grandparent has the class `.filter-1`, its immediate parent ***does not***... and that's enough to satisfy the *any descendant selector* (ie. the `[SPACE]`) preceding the `p` in the CSS Rule:

```
:not([class^="filter-"]) p
```

The only way to get around this is to replace the rule with:

```
:not([class^="filter-"]) > * > p
```

and this now works:

```css
.filter-1 {
  color: red;
}

:not([class^="filter-"]) > * > p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filter-1">
  <div>
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**But...**

the CSS Rule is now **tightly bound** to the HTML structure and the amended CSS rule above won't now apply to:

```
<div class="filter-2">
  <p>Test.</p>
</div>
```

See:

```css
.filter-1 {
  color: red;
}

:not([class^="filter-"]) > * > p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filter-1">
  <div>
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filter-2">
  <p>Test.</p>
</div>
```

Instead, we now need to use **two rules**:

```
:not([class^="filter-"]) > p,
:not([class^="filter-"]) > * > p
```

The following conclusion emerges:

> We can *only* use `:not()` to exclude descendants when we also *explicitly*
>   describe the **HTML structure** in the CSS.

I now understand much more clearly what `@G-Cyrillus` meant by:

> *You need to mind the structure too*

---

### Next Steps:

Describing an infinite number of potential descendant structures in my CSS is clearly impractical, so I've:

1) reconfigured my architecture to allow more complex **descendant relationships** to be described elsewhere

and

2) optimised my exclusion query to:

```
body > :not([id^="filter-"]):not([class^="filter-"])
```

Thanks very much again, `@G-Cyrillus` - I've only made it as far as this due to your substantial assistance in the comment section.